# How to hide the database login credential in the SAS program to connect teradata database

Tags: sas, teradata

How to hide the login credential in the SAS program to connect teradata database

Comment: How are you connecting?  Using a libname, or ODBC passthrough? If ODBC then have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157160/odbc-password-security-in-sas

Comment: THis is a nice overview: http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2010/11/23/five-strategies-to-eliminate-passwords-from-your-sas-programs/

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to obscure your credentials in your code take a look at [proc pwencode](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/secref/62092/HTML/default/viewer.htm%23a002595992.htm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SAS wallets for this. Your credentials are then deployed on your Unix system and picked up as variables (UID & PWD) in SAS code. Check your SAS wallet generation utility.